# How to programmatically identify binary calling convention?

Tags: c++, calling-conventions

I have a problem where I'm instrumenting stripped binaries; I don't know the start of `main()`. But there's always an `init()`, and `init()` calls `libc_start_main()`, which receives a pointer to main.

If I can instrument libc with analysis code to intercept the argument, then I can retrieve that address and place another pin callback there so that I can get it's arguments. The problem is, I don't know what the calling convention is; I was thinking, if I could boil this down to a matter of the calling convention, then I do this for any function. I did notice that `gdb` knows the calling convention of `libc_start_main()`, in fact it is so good, it knows the order of the arguments as well.

I did read a short note on stackoverflow that stated that the name of the function would yield the calling convention: « [How to find the calling convention of a third party dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162400/how-to-find-the-calling-convention-of-a-third-party-dll) »

If it's not possible to know the calling convention programmatically, what is the opinion on creating a local build of libc in order to be able to force a particular calling convention onto `__libc_start_main()`... you see my chain of thought. Does anybody think that this is a better approach, rather than solving it in the general case ?

Comment: I am afraid that solving the general case would require to follow the whole initialization function and track the final jump to the `main()` function. Meaning that it is probably much more efficient to have a collection of standard initialization functions than trying to solve it in the general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mention `__libc_start_main` it seems you need to worry only about Linux. In such case, the calling convention is [known and fixed](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/baselib---libc-start-main-.html). In most cases it will be [SystemV ABI](http://wiki.osdev.org/System_V_ABI) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I found that (at least on Linux) it was reliable to intercept _init and to read from a constant offset from the stack pointer was pretty reliable. I ended up producing a pintool that would do just that.

Comment: Well, your question was a classical XY problem: you needed to solve a specific, narrow case but you stated it in a very generic way.

Comment: I agree that your response is a correct/sufficient solution to the problem posed.